# How to create a sine wave in processing?

Tags: java, box2d

I would like to create a sine wave using vectors (as I am using `box2d`).

So far I have (in `void draw()`)

```
Vec2 mov2 = new Vec2(sin(angle)*scalar,0);

for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
   bridge.particles.get(j).body.setLinearVelocity(mov2);
}
```

where `bridge` is a chain of `particles`. However, this makes all the particles move back and forth at the same time whereas I would like to move like a sine wave so that each particle moves just slightly after the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some sort of offset between each of the particles inside your loop.

Example:

```
for( int i=0; i < 360; i++ ){   
         float x = 1 + i;
         float y = (float)(Math.sin( Math.toRadians(i+currentOffset)));
         bridge.particles.get(j).setTransform(x, y, 0);
 }
currentOffset+=1;
```