# Creating a single wave with Processing and box2d

Tags: processing, box2d

I have a series of bodies in a box2d world. These bodies are chained together. I would like to create a sine wave along the bodies when the mouse is pressed. I only want this wave to happen once and it should continue along the length of the bodies at the same amplitude until it gets to the end and then stop until the mouse is pressed once more.

At the moment I have this:

```java
float angle = 0.0;
float scalar = 1.2;
float speed = 0.01;
void mousePressed() {  
    for (int j = 0; j < 91; j++) {
        float x = sin(j+angle)*scalar;  
        float y = 0;       
        Vec2 mov2 = new Vec2(x,y);
        bridge.particles.get(j).body.setLinearVelocity(mov2);   
        angle+=speed;
  }
}
```

However this causes the bodies to become one continuous wave which just expands outwards as below (only trying this on the left strand at the moment):

[image]

How can I create one single wave moving downwards as described?

Using the amended code from @dfour I used:

```java
void mousePressed() { 
     int frequency = 10; // sine frequency (larger for longer wave)
    double fullCircle = Math.toRadians(180); // get 1 full iteration of a circle in radians;
    float x=0;
    float y=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
        if(i > fullCircle*frequency){
            // after first wave so output 0
            //System.out.println(0); 
        }else{
            // part of first sinewave so output wave value
            x =(float)Math.sin(i/frequency);
            Vec2 mov2 = new Vec2(x,y);
            print(" x: "+x);
            System.out.println(Math.sin(i/frequency));
            bridge.particles.get(i).body.setLinearVelocity(mov2);
        }
    }
}
```

but this has given me the following with the wave not actually progressing down the line of bodies:[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Comment: Sure thats why both tags are in. But the problem may also be a java one

Comment: Is there a reason you're using box2d if you want to control the bodies yourself? If you know where you want the bodies to be, why don't you just draw them there instead of relying on a physics engine?

Comment: @ KevinWorkman I need to use box2d as I am modelling some other interactions of boxes with the chain of bodies which I haven't shown. Having said that, it shouldn't really matter that I'm using box2d should it- I can get the object's location whether it's box 2d or not. I just dont know how to do the single sine wave

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How to create a sine wave in processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300125/how-to-create-a-sine-wave-in-processing)?

Comment: @LouisLangholtz no its not. That example causes the whole string to oscillate. What I am looking for is different as all I want is one wave that passes down the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get a single wave from for a sine you just need to loop through and once the first wave is finished output 0;

```java
    int frequency = 10; // sine frequency (larger for longer wave)
    double fullCircle = Math.toRadians(360); // get 1 full iteration of a circle in radians;
    for(double i = 0; i < 75 ; i++){
        if(i > fullCircle*frequency){
            // after first wave so output 0
            System.out.println(0); 
        }else{
            // part of first sinewave so output wave value
            System.out.println(Math.sin(i/frequency));
        }
    }
```

Edit:

I have tested this using the LibGdx framework and it all works. To apply this to your code you will need to add a timer field to store the time:

```java
private float sineTimer = 50f; //initially 50f as 0 would start wave
private final int PARTICLES = 40; // the amount of particles in your bridge
```

Then in your clickMethod add:

```java
sineTimer = -35f; // resets timer
```

Now in your main loop add:

```java
sineTimer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 10; // increment time since last frame

    int frequency = 3; // sine frequency (larger for longer wave)
    float fullCircle = (float) Math.toRadians(360); // get 1 full iteration of a circle in radians;
    // loop through all particles
    for(int i = 0; i < PARTICLES ; i++){
        float offset = i; // set base offset
        offset+=sineTimer; // add timer value to offset
        // if offset is lower than 0 or past first sine wave set particle to default place
        if(offset > fullCircle*frequency || offset < 0){
            bridgeParticles.get(i).setTransform(32,i, 0);
        }else{ // else apply sine position (I used x*3 here to amplifiy sine on x axis)
            float x =(float)Math.sin(offset/frequency);
            bridgeParticles.get(i).setTransform((x *3) + 32, i, 0);

        }
    }
```

**Code amended for Processing environment:**

```java
private float sineTimer = 50f; //initially 50f as 0 would start wave
private final int PARTICLES = 40; // the amount of particles in your bridge

void draw(){
     sineTimer += 0.5; // increment time since last frame

        int frequency = 23; // sine frequency (larger for longer wave)
        float fullCircle = (float) Math.toRadians(180); 
        for(int i = 0; i < PARTICLES ; i++){
            float offset = i; // set base offset
            offset+=sineTimer; // add timer value to offset
            if(offset > fullCircle*frequency || offset < 0){
                bridge.particles.get(i).body.setTransform(box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(200,i*10), 0);
            }else{ 
                float x =(float)Math.sin(offset/frequency);
                bridge.particles.get(i).body.setTransform(box2d.coordPixelsToWorld((x *125) +200, i*10), 0);
            }
        } 
    }

    void mousePressed() { 
    sineTimer = -35f; // resets timer 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @dfour...please see the amended code. One of the biggest issues I have is that the wave doesn't move down the chain of bodies

Comment: @SebastianZeki I have added a full example which works in LibGdx framework, hopefully, you will be able to convert this to your needs. :)

Comment: Thanks @dfour. I have added the Processing version. At the moment the wave is passing from bottom to top. How can I change it's direction so it runs top to bottom?

Comment: OK got it by changing to offset-=sineTimer